# Control values via GUI timeline Windows Forms C#

Tags: windows, winforms, timeline

I want to control some values based on keyframes placed on timeline (Like in adobe premiere pro you can build a graph of some parameter) How do i achieve this using windows forms? Do i need to create a custom control for this?[Example of keyframes on timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVIYI.png)

Comment: if it's easier to do in WPF...you could always us a WPF control host

Answer (score -1):

**Yes**, you would be required to create custom windows form controls.

1. Break each of the components into separate custom controls.

> You would need to create about 4 custom controls, each having about 2 to 4 sub controls.

Good Luck.